# Populate combobox using VLOOKUP

Tags: vba

I have a combobox that I'm trying to populate via another combobox.  I'm attempting this with vlookup.

Currently I have the following code which isn't working and I know I'm doing it wrong.

```
Private Sub ComboBox196_Change()
    Dim arg1 As String, arg3 As Integer
    'Dim MyRange As Range
    'Dim arg4 As Boolean
    'arg1 = ComboBox196.Value
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Setup").Range("SOMETITLES")
    If ComboBox196.Value = "Title" Then
        arg3 = 7
    ElseIf ComboBox196.Value = "Appraisal" Then
        arg3 = 24
    Else
        arg3 = 2
    End If
    Me.ComboBox197 = Application.VLookup(ComboBox196.Value, Worksheets("Setup").Range("SOMETITLES"), arg3, False)

End Sub
```

I'm getting a type mismatch error.  So again, my question is what do I need to do to populate my combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the case that Vlookup is returning an error, which could cause your type mismatch error. Go through your sub by stepping through in debug mode and use Debug.Print to see what values some things are. Please update when more detail when you can.

Replace

```
Me.ComboBox197 = Application.VLookup(ComboBox196.Value, Worksheets("Setup").Range("SOMETITLES"), arg3, False)
```

With:

```
Me.ComboBox197.Value = Application.VLookup(ComboBox196.Value, Worksheets("Setup").Range("SOMETITLES"), arg3, False)
```

Comment: I think part of my problem is that I'm trying to get multiple values at once.  After reviewing my range, I figured out that my range is indeed correct.  Any thoughts?